# Why doesn't LINQ implement ICollection<T> (or other interfaces) when possible?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this example:

```csharp
List<int> GetLengths(ICollection<string> strings) =>
    strings
        .Select(s => s.Length)
        .ToList();
```

If `Select()` checked that the input collection implements `ICollection<T>` and that its length is known in advance, it could have returned `ICollection<T>` too, so that `ToList()` would initialize the resulting list with capacity. Instead, the list adds each value one by one, expanding its storage log(N) times.

Is there any reason it's not done so in LINQ?

**Update**: since there are many questions about my suggestion, here are some justifications for my concept:

1. LINQ already [returns](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L42-L44) many different implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`. IMO there is nothing wrong with adding another iterator that implements one more interface.
2. A read-only `ICollection<T>` doesn't have to be materialized in memory, it only has to have `Count`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/zX5fdZEf) is an example of a bare implementation of `ICollection<T>` that behaves similar to `Enumerable.Repeat<T>()` except it calls a delegate to generate each element. It throws exceptions left and right, but [so the stock `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` does](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ReadOnlyCollection.cs#L59-L89).
3. The `List<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)` constructor already [checks](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L79-L91) if `collection` also implements `ICollection<T>`, so that the list can allocate its storage in advance. It doesn't violate any interfaces or conventions.
4. From the architectural point of view, implementing `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` would make more sense, but unfortunately, it's often neglected in the BCL itself, and the `List<T>` constructor doesn't check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizing the `source.Select().ToList()`, as well as the `source.Select().ToDictionary()`, was discussed a few years ago (2015) in this GitHub issue: [System.Linq performance improvement suggestions](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14366)

The suggestions were reviewed, and the decision was to not implement the optimizations. Here is an excerpt from the last post in the thread, by Stephen Toub, Sep 15, 2015.

> Through this thread as well as a bunch of PRs that have happened in the interim, we did agree that we don't want to expose existing collection interfaces out of LINQ, e.g. the object returned by Select shouldn't implement `ICollection<T>`, but we are ok with and have introduced additional internal interfaces to help curry certain information through the built-in operators, e.g. the iterator implemented by `Select` implements `IArrayProvider` so that its `ToArray` implementation can be optimized to work on the original array with complete knowledge of its size, using its indexer rather than going through `IEnumerable`, etc.
>
> At this point, given the original tasks called out on this thread, it looks like the only concrete remaining items would be around specializing methods like `ToDictionary` to have more knowledge of the original source. I suggest that if someone wants to implement such optimizations and do detailed measurements, such optimizations with associated measurements could be submitted as individual PRs, and an issue like this isn't needed to track them. So I'm going to leave this closed and not open new issues. Obviously folks should feel free to open subsequent issues / PRs for individual topics to be discussed / solutions implemented.

IMHO these internal LINQ optimizations are very much desirable.

---

**Update:** Apparently the `source.Select().ToList()` and `source.Select().ToArray()` operations have been optimized at a later stage of .NET's evolution, as can be demonstrated experimentally with this demo:

```
byte[] source = new byte[1_000_000];
long mem0 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
List<byte> result = source.Select(n => (byte)1).ToList();
long mem1 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
Console.WriteLine($"Allocated: {mem1 - mem0:#,0} bytes");
```

Output on .NET 6, Release mode:

```
Allocated: 1,000,232 bytes
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mNyy8Z)

So the `byte` array was projected and then materialized to a
`List<byte>` in one go, without log(N) allocations and expansions.

Answer (score 1):

> If `Select()` checked that the input collection implements `ICollection<T>` and that its length is known in advance, it could have returned `ICollection<T>` too

Whilst it could, that would mean `Select` would have to immediately return a materialised collection.

`Select` returns an iterator, which can be passed through other LINQ methods (e.g. `Where`), whilst still requiring only a single iteration of the source.

Returning a collection at each stage would likely be less efficient in many queries.

Comment: A read-only `ICollection<T>` doesn't need to be materialized, it only has to have `Count`.

Comment: @DmitryFedorkov on the contrary, an `ICollection<T>` is *already* materialized. Besides, nobody says that the source is a collection itself, it can be an infinite iterator. Or at least, a long running one

Comment: @DmitryFedorkov How would the count be computed, if the collection wasn't materialized in some way?

Comment: Theoretically an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` could be returned, with the `Count` being copied from the source collection (`ICollection<T>`) needs to be mutable. However, this type implies a materialised collection, not a potential lazy-loading iterator. Why would you need to call `ToList()` on a collection?

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay yes, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` would be preferable from the architectural point of view. But it's not widely used in .NET itself; in particular, the List constructor doesn't check if the input collection implements it.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay and again, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` doesn't have to be materialized. It only needs `Count`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos an example of an `ICollection<T>` that is **not** materialized is the [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection). From the docs: *"Lazy evaluation. The MatchCollection object is populated as needed on a match-by-match basis. It is equivalent to the regular expression engine calling the `Regex.Match` method repeatedly and adding each match to the collection."*

Comment: @TheodorZoulias except it was already evaluated to get the count of matches. What gets lazily evaluated are the actual match values. This doesn't change the fact that `IReadOnlyCollection` isn't a separate type of collection but a way to handle collections in a read-only manner. Or that LINQ is a query language to anything, and the primary target was databases. Not objects. And the interface supported by *all* containers was IEnumerable, not ICollection, for 7 years when LINQ was introduced. I'd say more, when you count the COM interfaces

Comment: @DmitryFedorkov and how would that count get calculated without *executing* the query ... to the database? Or a remote service through OData? LINQ is a query-to-anything language, not just in-memory containers. What you asked was tried in F#, only against in-memory containers. It *depends* on F# strong type inference, otherwise you'd have to create duplicate methods for every possible interface or collection. When it works yes, it's faster. Until it doesn't, because some methods are missing. These may be *your* extension methods that expected a specific interface but the inference used another

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not making broad claims about everything. All I said is that your statement *"an `ICollection<T>` is already materialized"* is not always true, and I provided a counter-example from the standard .NET libraries. If you had prefixed your statement with *"in most cases"*, then I would have no reason to intervene.